# Not getting carousel in Rich Result SERP

Tags: seo, search-engines

My website contains profile pages, and each profile page has multiple videos. We have added the `ItemList` schema to every profile page. It has been a month since we added it, but we are still not receiving any rich results or carousels. There are no errors in the search console, and the structured data is valid through the Schema Validator.

We have added the item list schema with the correct data set, ideally, it would have started showing those results but is not showing currently.

This is a short video application and we are targeting to show the carousel for those videos in the Google search (more specifically short video carousel section on Google search). e.g. when you search "moj" you will see one carousel at the end.